# Submit form, clone form, submit only new form, clone form, etc

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, submit, clone

I have a form I want to submit it to SQL, without page reloading, because the input shall not be deleted. 
After that, I want to clone the form. 
The new form should be filledwith new input, and then also be sent to SQL.

It only submits the Input of the first form. I know, it is because of the same ID, but I don't know how to solve it.

This is my form

```
<div class="div">    
<form class="test1">
    <textarea type="text" name="testeintrag"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Neue Zeile" 
onclick="clone_test();versendentest();return false;">
</form>
</div>
```

This the clone-code:

```
var i=2;    
function clone_test(){

$('.test1').clone().attr('class', 'test'+ i++).appendTo('.div');
//$(".test").clone().appendTo(".div");

  };
```

And this the send-Code:

```
function versendentest() {    


var testeintrag = $("#testeintrag").val();


$.post("save_test.php", { 
testeintrag:testeintrag},


);
};
```

Comment: `testeintrag` is a name attribute and not an `id` as per your code

Comment: Did I understand correctly that basically you want to save same form twice? In that case should you do that on back-end?

Comment: First a question in return: why do you need to clone the form? Couldn’t you handle the form post, show a flash message to inform the user and then reset the form?

Comment: It's for planning a lesson in school.

The user should see and change things he wrote, so I don't want to reset the form. 

So he writes the first line ( a line is a form with 7 Input fields). Then the second. While planning the second line, he noticed something in the first line and wants to change it.

Krishna Yes, that's right. I tried different things and didn't change that back.
maximelian It's the same form but with different inputs.